# Is there a "mathematics fiction" genre?

Tags: science, hard-sci-fi, mathematics, genre

The science fiction genre has been and is still an area in which visionary authors can express their ideas about new sciences.
Many successful academic research were influenced by works of science fiction (see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37513/about-science-fiction-influence-on-science)).

Is there an equivalent for mathematics ?

As a mathematician, I would be very interested in a "mathematics fiction" genre, in the sense of an area in which visionary authors can express their ideas about new mathematics.
Unfortunately, this genre would be very hard and reserved to a few insiders.
 In addition, to have myself tried, it is most often poorly viewed by mathematicians...

Does such "mathematics fiction" already exist ? examples ?

**Edit**: here are two links to others questions close to this one (but not exactly the same):
[Fiction books about mathematicians ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101644/fiction-books-about-mathematicians/)
[Movies about mathematics/mathematicians](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77279/movies-about-mathematics-mathematicians)

Comment: There is the Niven short-story titled after a paper: "Rotating Cylinders and the Possibility of Global Causality Violation".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a potential genre that is similar to, but distinct from, science fiction.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about another genre; it might be appropriate for Meta, or possibly a different SE site.

Comment: @user14111 I'm well aware that science-fiction is not off topic for ... Sci-fi.se.  I've no idea why you would belief it seems that way.  While you *could* argue that math is a subset of science, and therefore stories involving fictional math would be on topic, that doesn't seem to be what the op is asking about.  Or, at least, not all he's asking about. He seems focused on real math that made its debut under the guise of fiction, while asking for a list of examples, and further discussion on the idea.  Math as a subset of sci-fi is marginal. Lists and discussion ate clearly off topic.

Comment: An argument could be made that Asimov's Foundation series (particularly 'Prelude to Foundation') are stories in such a sub-genre: "what if someone invented a mathematical theory that predicted perfectly the future of mankind?"

Comment: @dmckee Rotating Cylinders... (the story) is more about physics than math. The scientific paper that it's based on was written by Physicist Frank Tipler.  However, another Niven story, Infinite Series, is based on math...

Comment: [*Pi*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138704) might qualify as "mathematical fiction."

Comment: The fact that the answers so far are each "here are a couple of examples" demonstrates why this question needs to be fixed.  It is clearly gathering list answers.

Comment: Heinlein's "And He Built A Crooked House..." involves a house built in the shape of an [unfolded tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hcube_fold.gif).  The house folds up as the result of an earthquake, with interesting consequences for the prospective buyers who are in the process of touring it with a real estate agent.

Comment: Not yet, but they seem very interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudy_Rucker
http://www.rudyrucker.com/

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're trying to make with your most recent edit. 1) You're linking to another stack exchange site. What they do or do not deem as an acceptable question has no bearing on what we do. 2) Even *they* closed both of those questions - for being off-topic or no-longer-relevant.

Comment: I posted these links because I just find them and  their content is close to this issue. I think they contain informations that may interest people who upvoted or answered this issue. On the other hand, I fully understand the purpose of your comment, your goal is that people meet well the ethic of this site, however, don't you think your comment is overzealous ?

Comment: There is a story by Hardy in which a mathematician steals a theorem of another guy and kills him (?) -- this is mathematics fiction in that the theorem does not exist just like science fiction in which the actual invention/technology does not exist. Not too exciting, frankly, to me but I think this is actually "mathematics fiction."

Answer (score 11):

I don't think it exists in the form you describe - mathematics that is new in the academic sense is invariably extremely abstract and complex, which is almost impossible to write *stories* about, except in the style of [A Beautiful Mind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Beautiful_Mind_%28film%29), i.e. human drama that involves mathematicians, but glosses over the actual math.

The only kind of “mathematics fiction” I've seen is rather the opposite: science fiction that is based on actual math, but that's invariably relatively old math that people have had some time to come to grips with, even if it may still appear very complex and mysterious to non-mathematicians.

The classic in this area is, of course, [Flatland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland). A newer example would be Greg Egan's short story "Wang's carpets", which later got incorporated into the novel [Diaspora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora_%28novel%29) - which incidentially also features a community of AIs who've made mathematics their main occupation. They call the virtual place where they do this the "Truth Mines".

Comment: the authors Greg Egan seems very interesting, he also wrote "permutation city" based on ideas of the mathematicians John von Neumann about self-replicating machine.

Comment: The mathematician Vaughan Jones (initiator of the subfactor theory and fields medal) gave a talk (available on internet) in which he compare "flatland" with its theory of planar algebras.

Answer (score 4):

Alex Kasman has a [Mathematical Fiction](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/) website. That would be the place for the kind of stuff you are looking for, though I believe his scope is much broader than what you have in mind.

Comment: thank you, this website seems very interesting, I will explore it to see if it contains what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There definitely is, and the progenitor was, arguably, none other than Lewis Carroll, aka Charles Dodgson. According to modern research - especially [Melanie Bayley's work](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3826762?uid=3739808&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21102414034111) - the Alice books were a satire of abstract and non-Euclidean math (which Dodgson was not a big fan of).

See also: [[2]](http://www.newscientist.com/article/mg20427391.600-alices-adventures-in-algebra-wonderland-solved.html#.Uc4wftj3Nm8), [[3]](http://www.alice-in-wonderland.net/alice8.html).

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundation_series) series, from Asimov? The whose story is based on a new type of mathematics that can predict the actions of large groups of people. Would that fall into the category you're looking for?

Comment: This is near to what I'm looking for. I read the Foundation series with a lot of interests. But it's not yet exactly this. I'm looking for a genre with more precise mathematics, not strictly academic mathematics of course but nearest to that. Of course, the mathematic genre of the "Foundation series" you are talking about, should be more used by the authors, in my opinion, because it's wonderful!